How it's possible to deploy RMarkdown document on Posit without rendering (calculations) it?
I have a data and modelling pipeline that takes me 5h of local calculations. If I deploy it on Posit it's taking me 5h (rendering locally) + 5h (rendering on Posit) = 10h of calculations.
Does anyone know how to deploy RMarkdown doc without local and posit rendering and start doing it by schedule only.
Any ideas are welcome!
